# replace COM objects in coldfusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to replace COM objects in my ColdFusion 9 code. Before we used to use ColdFusion 7 and recently upgraded to 9, but version 9 does not support COM objects. Is there any way I can use the COM? Or how can I replace the COM objects with something else?

My code :

```
<cfobject type="COM" name="objGetSession" class="DlBizApp21.dlGMUBiz" action="create">
<cfset objSession = objGetSession.CurrentSession>
<cfset loginx = objSession.Login("administrator", "abcd", "", "DBProd", "docxyz")>

<cfscript>
    objInquiry = CreateObject("COM","DlBizDoc21.DocumentInquiry");
    objDocTypes = CreateObject("COM","DLBizDoc21.DocumentTypes");
    objAdors = CreateObject("Com","adodb.recordset");
</cfscript>
```

Comment: ColdFusion 9 still [supports COM objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-714e.html). Did the operating system get upgraded as well? Perhaps the COM objects are not compatible with the newer operating system. Can you get updated versions? Also be cognizant of the bitness (32bit vs 64bit).

Comment: Step 1 for replacing a com object is to determine what it does.

Comment: @Miguel-F - We are using 64 bit vs 64 bit

Comment: Was the old ColdFusion 7 server 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: @Miguel-F -  it was 32 bit

Comment: @DanBracuk - How do i replace?

Comment: ***Step 1 for replacing a COM object is to determine what it does*** - nobody here knows what DlBizApp21 or DlBizDoc21 do; it's not possible to suggest a replacement without knowing what is to be replaced. You and/or your colleagues need to look at the CF7 instance and determine what functionality the COM object is providing there.

Comment: *ColdFusion 9 still supports COM objects.* Last I heard 32bit versions still support COM, [64bit versions do not](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-limitations-running-coldfusion-64.html).

Comment: Correct @Leigh and that is partially why I was asking the bitness that the OP is running. So I guess they have 2 choices. Run ColdFusion 9 on a 32 bit server and _potentially_ be able to run the existing COM objects or run ColdFusion 9 on 64 bit server and find Java replacements for whatever the COM objects did.